# Why I'm getting 'mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given' this warning?

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\register.php on line 34
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\membership\register.php on line 37
> COde :

Line 33:

```
$user_query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1";
```

Line 34:

```
$count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);
```

Line 36:

```
$email_query = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email ='$email' LIMIT 1";
```

Line 37:

```
$count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

if ($user_query>0){
    $message = "Your username already in use";
} elseif($email_query>0) {
    $message = "Your email already in use";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it expects a resource, not a string like you're passing into it.
You have to execute your SQL query before trying to get the rows:

```
$user_query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($user_query);

$count_username = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Also, all of the  `mysql_*`functions are deprecated.
Either use `PDO` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `MySQLI` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Currently, your query is also most likely vulnerable to SQL injection ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), escape strings that are user input or use prepared statements to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're not running a query. You need to use the following:

```
$user_query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1"
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_query); //NOTE MYSQLI, not MYSQL!
$count_username = mysql_num_rows($conn, $result);
```

As you see above, I'm using mysqli, not mysql. You should stop using mysql as it's deprecated. Mysqli is very similar, almost identical for what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't downvote but most likely because you can't mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.